# Angular - inserting data to a component after getting by selector

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm inserting an empty component dynamically into a page. For simplicity purposes here I've hardcoded the import. Is there a way of passing simple html to that component before insertion?

page.page.ts

```
this.componentService
  .getComponentBySelector("app-content", () =>
    import("src/app/components/content.module").then(m => m.ContentModule)
    )
  .then(componentRef => {
    // pass "<span>William</span> to the imported component first before inserting into the page
    this.container.insert(componentRef.hostView);
});
```

content.component.ts

```
import { SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss'],
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() content: SafeHtml;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

content.component.html

```
<div>Greetings {{ content }}</div>
```

Comment: You should have `componentRef.instance` or something along those lines, giving you access to the class instance created

Comment: Would you be able to possibly give me an example please? I'm not 100% following you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out perfectly. This is the answer for anyone else who may be having the same issue:

I used ngx-dynamic-hooks. It allows code and components to be written dynamically alongside each other.

https://github.com/MTobisch/ngx-dynamic-hooks